# First-order non-homogeneous recurrence relations with variable coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations

Looking at the method for solving recurrence relations given on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients), I found myself confused by some aspects of the method. To save people tabbing backwards and forwards, here is what it says:

> For [a] general first-order non-homogeneous linear recurrence relation
> with variable coefficients:
>
> $$a_{n+1}=f_{n}a_{n}+g_{n},\qquad f_{n}\neq 0,$$
>
> there is [...] a nice method to solve it:
>
> $$a_{n+1}-f_{n}a_{n}=g_{n}$$
> $${\frac {a_{n+1}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}f_{k}}}-{\frac {f_{n}a_{n}}{\prod _{k=0}^{n}f_{k}}}={\frac {g_{n}}{\prod _{k=0}^{n}f_{k}}}$$
> $${\frac {a_{n+1}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}f_{k}}}-{\frac {a_{n}}{\prod _{k=0}^{n-1}f_{k}}}={\frac {g_{n}}{\prod _{k=0}^{n}f_{k}}}$$
>
> Let
>
> $$A_{n}={\frac {a_{n}}{\prod _{k=0}^{n-1}f_{k}}},$$
>
> Then
>
> $$A_{n+1}-A_{n}={\frac {g_{n}}{\prod _{k=0}^{n}f_{k}}}$$
> $$\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}(A_{m+1}-A_{m})=A_{n}-A_{0}=\sum _{m=0}^{n-1}{\frac {g_{m}}{\prod _{k=0}^{m}f_{k}}}$$
> $${\frac {a_{n}}{\prod _{k=0}^{n-1}f_{k}}}=A_{0}+\sum _{m=0}^{n-1}{\frac {g_{m}}{\prod _{k=0}^{m}f_{k}}}$$
> $$a_{n}=\left(\prod _{k=0}^{n-1}f_{k}\right)\left(A_{0}+\sum _{m=0}^{n-1}{\frac {g_{m}}{\prod _{k=0}^{m}f_{k}}}\right)$$
>
> If we apply the formula to $a_{n+1}=(1+hf_{nh})a_{n}+hg_{nh}$ and the
> take the limit $h \to 0$, we get the formula for first order linear
> differential equations with variable coefficients; the sum becomes an
> integral, and the product becomes the exponential function of an
> integral.

I have questions:

1. Are $f_n$ and $g_n$ functions or sequences of coefficients? I note that the heading for the section states that this is a discussion of linear recurrence relations. But obviously, if all we can discover are specific coefficients $f_n,g_n$ for some chosen $n$, then we are no closer to finding a general pattern for the sequence $a_1,a_2,...$
2. What is meant by $f_{n h}$ and $g_{nh}$? If the answer to question 1 is that they are functions, then do we have $f_{nh}=f(n+h)$? It's not at all clear.
3. Basically, I just don't understand that last paragraph. It feels like we get to the tricky bit and then hand-waving takes over from maths.

What I am after is a clear understanding of what happens *after* the last equation in the section. If it's not possible to work the last part through in a general sense, then I'd very much appreciate a specific example - but the general approach is preferable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last paragraph is no longer about the recurrence relation itself, but about the relationship with its continuous counterpart, which is a differential equation. Compare to [First-order (*linear differential*) equation with variable coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients).